# Drill down through many attributes cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I am trying to find information inside a fairly complex page. How do I use cheerio to drill through all the way down to the information I am trying to find?

The information is in 
html body #container #main div#content.cf span dvi.issportcontent ul.tab li a.large

Code that I am starting to build

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const options = {
    uri: `https://www.travsport.se/sresultat?kommando=tevlingsdagVisa&tevdagId=568521&loppId=1118529&source=S#lopp`,
    transform: function (body) {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  };

  console.log(options);

  rp(options)
  .then(($) => {
    console.log($('html')); <---- trying to log the info here. 
    $('ul.tab').each(function(i, elem) {
      var onClickText = $(elem)[0];
      var location = onClickText.search('valdTevlingsdag=');

  })
})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of the 12 `a.large` elements I assume you're looking for:

```
console.log($('#content > span > div > ul > li > a.large'));
```